# What are the links/tags/bookmarks starting with "E" in vim's help docs?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

In Vim's `:help`, there are many links/tags/bookmarks starting with `E`. For example, typing `:help E355` takes you to a list of all of Vim's options. But there are hundreds of "E" style links/tags/bookmars. What are they, and why are they in the format "E" + number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are error tags. From [02.8 Finding help](https://vimhelp.org/usr_02.txt.html#02.8)

> If you see an error message that you don't understand, for example:
>
> ```
>     E37: No write since last change (use ! to override)
> ```
>
> You can use the error ID at the start to find help about it:
>
> ```
>     :help E37
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`E355` is an error id, useful for looking up the explanation of any error you might encounter.

Many of them are rather cryptic, though. Doing `:help E355`, for example, leads to the following, which is not very helpful:

```
                                                        E355
A jump table for the options with a short description can be found at |Q_op|.
```

See `:help message.txt`.